# Executing a stored procedure on SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I'm execute two values for a certain parameter on my stored procedure in SQL server. What I have is below.

**Parameters:**

- @RuleId Varchar(50),
- @Date DATE,
- @Amount MONEY,
- @Instance INT,
- @Activity INT

when I execute I type in the following:

```
Exec dbo.Storedproc1 'Stored Procedure Number 1', '1/6/15', 60000, 1, 700
```

The issue is with the activity parameter. I want to put in two values for the activity type parameter, and I'm unable to do so.

Can someone shed some light on how to do this please? Thanks!

Comment: either pass those values as a single combined value (e.g. a string) and then split inside the sproc, or change your sproc to accept more arguments

Comment: I'd like to do this without adding arguments, and input multiple exec values for this parameter. Can that be done?

Comment: then you'll have to modify your sproc with special handling for that argument.

Comment: table valued type https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb510489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: You cannot do this without making changes to your stored procedure.

Comment: I don't think a table value parameter applies to what I'm trying to do because it is a fixed value, and cannot be changed whereas my parameter can be changed.

Comment: what kind of changes do I need to make to the SP in order for me to do this? Do I need to add extra parameters?

Comment: As @MarcB suggested, you can either change your procedure to accept multiple `activities` in one parameter (something like `Exec dbo.Storedproc1 'Stored Procedure Number 1', '1/6/15', 60000, 1, '700,800,900'` where your code in the SP will parse out each value to use it) OR... change the procedure to accept more parameters. Those are your options. We can't really help you make these changes, or suggest code because we have no idea what your SP looks like.

Comment: I did type in '700,800,900' however it yielded no results, and I cannot add more parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass multiple values to an `Integer`-type parameter.

You would have to change the datatype of that parameter in your stored procedure, to either a Table-type parameter, or a varchar-type.

Then you would have to change the logic of your stored procedure to handle the incoming parameter the way you want depending on the new type.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thank you!